# A question about relative motion and how to make sense of it

Tags: kinematics, vectors, inertial-frames, velocity, relative-motion

So, here is the question:
Assuming the 2D Cartesian system and the basis vectors $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$, we have two cars A and B located at (0,6) and (-30,0) respectively. Car A starts moving with a constant velocity of -3 m/s $\hat{j}$ and Car B with 4 m/s $\hat{i}$. The question is to find the minimum separation between these two cars.

I understand there is a way we could solve this using calculus (specifically derivatives), but that way involves a lot of calculations. So my professor explained a way to solve this using relative motion, i.e assuming either body's frame and working out the problem in that frame. In here, particularly, if we assume to be in the frame of B, we would see that A has a velocity of $-(4 \hat{i}+3 \hat{j}) \frac{m}{s}$. If we draw out the line that the body A traverses in the frame of B, we get the line 3x-4y+24=0. Now the thing which the professor did was confusing to me, they said that the minimum separation between them is going to be the shortest distance of the point where car B was initially, to the line I mentioned above. What I do not get is that, why did they say that the shortest distance is from that point (-30,0) to the line? I mean it felt weird to me because B's origin (their own particular co-ordinate system's) is changing all over the time. So how did they conclude we have to calculate the distance from there? I am sorry if I could not make complete sense.

Comment: the minimum separation between those two cars is zero because those two cars are collide at t=5.14 [s]

Comment: @Eli, it's not possible, because at t=5.14 s, car A is at (0, -9.42) and the car B is at (-9.44, 0). The distance between them is not zero.

Comment: from your data I got those two equations car A
$y=6-3\,t~$ car B $~x=-30+4\,t$

Comment: Yes, how did you conclude that they collide then?

Comment: well y=x is wrong ?

Comment: I don't get you, you are indirectly saying that $k \times \hat{i} = g \times \hat{j}$ which is not true, where k and g are some constants and $\times$ means normal multiplication (here scaling of vectors). Although you could've done $|k \times \hat{i}| = |g \times \hat{j}|$

Answer (score 1):

The intuitive reason why you want the shortest distance from $B$ to the relative path is that if you were observing the motion of $A$ from car $B$, $A$ would *appear* to be moving along this relative path and would miss you by a certain distance, i.e. the shortest distance, because you (now located at the origin) are not on this path.

It probably doesn't help that the relative path you have quoted in your question is not actually correct:

The velocity of $A$ relative to $B$ is $$\left(\begin{matrix}0\\-3\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}4\\0\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}-4\\-3\end{matrix}\right)$$
The initial position of $A$ relative to $B$ is $$\left(\begin{matrix}0\\6\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}-30\\0\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}30\\6\end{matrix}\right)$$
Therefore at time $t$ the position of $A$ relative to $B$ is $$\underline{r}=\left(\begin{matrix}30\\6\end{matrix}\right)+t\left(\begin{matrix}-4\\-3\end{matrix}\right)$$

Note that the origin does not satisfy this equation, so there will be no collision.

In Cartesian form, this comes from $x=30-4t$ and $y=6-3t$. and eliminating $t$ gives $$\frac{30-x}{4}=\frac{6-y}{3}\implies 3x-4y-66=0$$

So the shortest distance between the cars is $\frac{66}{5}$

Comment: The initial position for (A) is (6,0). Then x = 36-4t and y = 0 -3t.

Comment: @R.W.Bird that's not what the question says

Comment: It looks to me like the instructor mapped "the trajectory of A in the frame of B" on the coordinate space of the non-frameshifted origin, with predictably confusing results. The OP's line equation can indeed be used to find the distance of closest approach by drawing the perpendicular line through (-30, 0) , as the instructor describes... but only because the line *isn't the trajectory of A* in that coordinate space.

Comment: @user3298777, thank you for your answer. The instructor did not change the position frames, but you did. In my case, if you use the distance from (-30,0) to the line I mentioned, you get the same 66/5 as the answer. But that wasn't my question. What I am confused with is that, as B is moving (considering we don't change the position frames), how do we "fix" the coordinate of B as (-30,0) and calculate the distance from there? I mean, B is moving wrt the origin (0,0).

Comment: the velocity of $A$ is adjusted to allow $B$ to remain stationary

Comment: Right I do get that, but what I cannot fathom is how the “constantly moving origin” is the point we have to take the distance from. I hope I am making sense?

Comment: Once you have fixed $B$ as the origin it is not moving.

Comment: What the instructor has done is to take a frame comoving with, but distant from, the initial position of B, such that at time 0, the origin of the new frame is in the same place as the origin of the old frame. I have to emphasize: plotting the line on the same coordinate axes is incorrect. The comoving coordinate space is not the original coordinate space. You won't be able to understand why it's right *because it's wrong*, even if you can extract a correct answer by making an equal and opposite mistake in interpretation of the mistakenly plotted graph.

Comment: Not trying to dump on your instructor, by the way. This kind of little technically incorrect time saver sometimes sneaks into your problem solving process, it happens to everyone.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @user3298777, but when I have fixed B as the origin, the frame of B is moving with respect to a ground observer and hence the origin of B is moving. So it kind of confuses me how this process actually works. I would like to know how does this make sense for a ground observer working out in B's frame.

Answer (score 1):

The initial frame shift is incorrect. Try shifting into the B frame, such that A is at (30, 6) on the line $3x-4y = 66$, then find the distance from that line to the origin. In the B frame, the position of B is always the origin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @gs. I get this way of going about the question, it makes complete sense. The part which still confuses me is how the moving frame's origin is always fixed, I get that in the frame of B, they always think of themselves as the origin. But I just cannot fathom it.

Comment: In any problem, unless it is given, you are free to choose the fame of reference. In this case, the moving frame is chosen with (B) at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

I get the line of motion for (A) moving in the system which is moving with (B) as: 3x – 4y -108 = 0.  A perpendicular line passing through (B) (at the origin of this system) is: y = -(4/3)x.  These two lines intersect at (12.96, -17.278).  The minimum distance is measured from the origin to this point.

Comment: I don't get how the equation of the line makes sense, what is your origin precisely @R.W Bird?

Comment: My mistake. I misread the question.